# Issues with my login

Tags: php, authentication

I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to setup a database for users to log in and sign up by using the code provided by [this website here](http://forums.devshed.com/php-faqs-and-stickies-167/how-to-program-a-basic-but-secure-login-system-using-891201.html).

My website is located at: http://cloudgaming.byethost7.com/.

The problem is that whenever I try to log in or sign up, this error shows up:

`Failed to connect to the database: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'dbusername'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I asked my girlfriend to try it as well, and she got the same error. If I pair the PHP document with CSS document, and place the PHP code into `<style>` tags, I don't get that error, but I don't get the CSS layout except the background. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It simply means your MySQL authentication failed, as your details are incorrect (username and/or password).

Comment: Can you post your PHP code? There is something wrong in your connection, re-check all your login info.

Comment: @Twan Which part of the code? The Login, or Register? Both are too long for these comments, sadly.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't put PHP code into the `<style>` tags... that's not where it's supposed to go.

Comment: @user3383128 The connection part, make sure it's there. Like stated in the answers below. Use your info in the space between the "". Don't post your info here, because that is the login data for your database.

Comment: @Twan I found it, marked the one that explained it easiest to me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your common.php file.

```
$username = "dbusername"; 
$password = "dbpassword";
```

Change above 2 lines with your host's username and password.

Most likely:

```
$username = "root"; 
$password = "";
```

or,

may be you are using your localhost settings on a remote web server. Change below lines with respective details.

```
$username = "dbusername"; 
$password = "dbpassword"; 
$host = "localhost";
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Serves me right for going full steam ahead and not reading into the code aha this works now :)

Answer (score 0):

//for connect database

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

mysql_select_db("your database_name",$con);

Comment: Please wrap code within code tags when posting.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $dbuser = "db user name"; 
        $dbpass = "db password";
        $dbhost = "your host name";
        $dbname = "the database name";

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
```

do like this.